# Testing function parameters one by one using a while loop in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am writing a script where I should test the parameters that the user give by using a while loop. The last parameter should always be "local" and there is no fixed number for parameters count ( We can add as many parameters as we want)

Here's my code so far :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo -n 'My OS is : '
unamestr=`uname`
echo $unamestr

i=1
while [ "${@:i}" != "local" ]
do
    if [ "${@:i}" == "mysql" ]
    then
        #add the repository
        wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
        sudo rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
        yum update
        #Install mysql
        sudo yum install mysql-server
        sudo systemctl start mysqld
    elif [ "${@:i}" == "chrome" ]
    then
        echo 'Installing Chrome'
    else
        echo 'Nothing'
    fi

    let i++
done
```

I need to know what should be the while condition in order to test all the parameters.

Comment: I don't find your answer @Inian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is right, just use a proper loop to loop over all the input arguments. Use this as an outer loop and have your checks inside,

```
for arg in "$@"; do

    # Proceed to next argument if the current is "local"
    [ "$arg" = "local" ] && continue

    if [ "$arg" = "mysql" ]
    then
        #add the repository
        wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
        sudo rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
        yum update
        #Install mysql
        sudo yum install mysql-server
        sudo systemctl start mysqld
    elif [ "$arg" = "chrome" ]
    then
        echo 'Installing Chrome'
    else
        echo 'Nothing'
    fi
done
```

This should be compatible in your `POSIX` shell `sh`.

Comment: This solved my problem!! Thanks and sorry for the delay :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the slice notation to index into `$@`, note that `"${@:i}"` takes all the positional parameters starting at position `i`. You'd need `"${@:i:1}"` to take only one. To run through all of them, get the count from `$#`, so something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while (( i <= $# )) ; do
    arg=${@:i:1}
    if [ "$arg" = that ] ; then
         ...
    fi
    let i++
done
```

Note that almost all of that (`let`, `((...))`, `==` with `[ .. ]` and the slice notation `${var:n:m}`) is extensions to the POSIX shell language, so the hashbang should probably indicate some other shell, like Bash.

As Inian showed in the other answer, the usual POSIX way to loop over all
positional parameters is

```
for arg in "$@" ; do...
```

or

```
for arg do ...
```

if you need to use the current index POSIXly, do something like

```
i=1
for arg do
    if [ "$#" -eq "$i" ] ; then echo "the last one" ; fi
    echo "$i: $arg"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```